# "Thus $\textbf{y}$ and $\textbf{z}$ are both elements of $S\cap S^\perp$"

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The step I am confused on is in yellow background

---

Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S^\perp$ be its orthogonal complement.

Let $\{\textbf{x}_1,\dots,\textbf{x}_r\}$ be a basis for $S$ and $\{\textbf{x}_{r+1},\dots,\textbf{x}_n\}$ be a basis for $S^\perp$

Suppose
$$
c_1\textbf{x}_1+\dots + c_r\textbf{x}_r + c_{r+1}\textbf{x}_{r+1} + \dots c_n\textbf{x}_n =0
$$

Defining $\textbf{y} =c_1\textbf{x}_1+\dots + c_r\textbf{x}_r$ and $\textbf{z} = c_{r+1}\textbf{x}_{r+1} + \dots c_n\textbf{x}_n$ we have that

$$
\textbf{y}+\textbf{z} =0
$$
thus
$$
\textbf{y}=-\textbf{z}
$$

> Thus $\textbf{y}$ and $\textbf{z}$ are both elements of $S\cap S^\perp$

I am confused on that last statement (in yellow)

Is the reasoning behind the step that $z\in S$ because it is $(-1) \textbf{y}$ and thus is a linear combination of the basis elements of $S$? (and similar reasoning for why $y\in S^\perp$)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since subspaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication, we have $y\in S$ and $z\in S^{\perp}$. So you're correct in saying that we also have $z\in S$ because $z=-y$ and $y\in S$ so $-y\in S$. Similarly for showing $y\in S^\perp$.